# CalDav Event Coloring: existing alternatives?

Tags: synchronization, caldav, vcalendar

It appears CalDav Event coloring is not supported - all events of one same calendar have the same color - the calendar's master color!

I am looking for an alternative way to get colored events within a "master-calendar" without creating as many calendars on my server as I have colors.

My first idea: create different calendars with different colors. Two issues here
1. Can I set a calendar's color via CalDav?

2. Is it possible to "embed" different calendars in one "master calendar", having one color for each sub-calendar?

The reason I'd like to achieve something similar is that I'd like to avoid creating several accounts for each one of the sub-calendar, which would, in turn, force the user to register calendars individually (ok, I could use auto-detection, but it makes things a bit more complex for syncing in my case-study).

Does anyone have a suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no RFC'ed standard on how to do colors on either calendars or events.

The iOS and OSX calendar clients only support a single calendar color, they can't color individual events (unlike Outlook, which has that extra 'color categories' feature).

You can set the Apple colors of a calendar via WebDAV. It is a (currently undocumented) Apple specific extension, a property on the calendar collection. Sample:

```
<calendar-color xmlns="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">#2952A3</calendar-color>
```

Use a regular PROPPATCH to set the color on an existing calendar (or within MKCOL when creating a collection):

```
PROPPATCH /your/calendar/url/ HTTP/1.1
...

<propertyupdate xmlns="DAV:">
  <set>
    <prop>
      <calendar-color xmlns="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">#2952A3</calendar-color>
    </prop>
  </set>
</propertyupdate>
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to embed calendars in other calendars in CalDAV: "Collections contained in calendar collections MUST NOT contain calendar collections at any depth, i.e., "nesting" of calendar collections within other calendar collections at any depth is not allowed." [RFC 4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-4.2)

Worse, most clients do not even allow calendars within arbitrary DAV collection hierarchies (that is, they only look at the calendar-home as a flat list and do not traverse non-calendar subcollections).

Summary: There is no 'reasonable' way to support per event colors, primarily because the Apple clients simply do not have that feature.

P.S.: Other CalDAV clients may have that feature (e.g. BusyCal), and embed the color in an event via an iCalendar X property, or again using a custom DAV property.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for clarity.
As for the iCal specific part - is there a google way to do it, even if it is not working on iOS / OSX ?

Comment: The Google web calendar supports a single per event color (unlike Outlook which supports multiple color categories). I don't know whether Google exposes the per event color in CalDAV, but you very likely have access to them via their proprietary GData protocol.

Comment: Just had a look at the GCal CalDAV traffic with iCal - the iCalendar entities do not seem to contain the color when transferred via CalDAV.

Comment: Yes I also saw that - too bad. Could you please provide with a request example for changing the calendar-color via http request (PROPPATCH) ?

Comment: That is trivial to Google. First hit has it all.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<propertyupdate xmlns="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"
xmlns:ical="http://apple.com/ns/ical/"
xmlns:C1="http://apple.com/ns/ical/:calendar-color">
  <set>
   <prop>
    <displayname>lehre</displayname>
    <ical:calendar-color>#f8f087ff</ical:calendar-color>
   </prop>
  </set>
</propertyupdate>

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a newer RFC which specifies color on calendar and event level.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7986

> 4. Modifications to Calendar Components

> This section details changes to the syntax defined in iCalendar
> [RFC5545].  New elements are defined in subsequent sections.

> calprops =/ *(
> ;
> ; The following are OPTIONAL,
> ; but MUST NOT occur more than once.
> ;
> uid / last-mod / url /
> refresh / source / **color**
> ;
> ; The following are OPTIONAL,
> ; and MAY occur more than once.
> ;
> name / description / categories /
> image
> ;
> )

> eventprop =/ *(
> ;
> ; The following are OPTIONAL,
> ; but MUST NOT occur more than once.
> ;
> **color** /
> ;
> ; The following are OPTIONAL,
> ; and MAY occur more than once.
> ;
> conference / image
> ;
> )

...

> 5.9.  COLOR Property

> Description:  This property specifies a color that clients MAY use
> when presenting the relevant data to a user.  Typically, this
> would appear as the "background" color of events or tasks.  The
> value is a case-insensitive color name taken from the CSS3 set of
> names, defined in Section 4.3 of [W3C.REC-css3-color-20110607].

But i was not able to make it work on event level with mac Calendar and iOS, though i would suspect that those clients come up with the RFC extension implementation earliest as the author is from Apple.

Also a litte sad that only CSS3 color names would be supported ;(

Comment: The errata allows rgb() values : https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/rfc7986